# Uncaught ReferenceError in Scala template

Tags: javascript, playframework

I am trying to access Scala values in javascript, but it is giving me error.

Scala template - login.scala.html :-

```
@import com.tempapp.Constants.Languages

<html>
   ...
</html>

<script>
var langs = @Languages.values; // Error
   ...
</script>
```

`Languages` is an Enum:-

```
public enum Languages{
   ENGLISH, VIETNAMESE;
}
```

> Error :- Uncaught ReferenceError: ENGLISHVIETNAMESE is not defined
>       at HTMLDocument. (merchant:282)
>       at j (jquery-2.1.4.min.js:2)
>       at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-2.1.4.min.js:2)
>       at Function.ready (jquery-2.1.4.min.js:2)
>       at HTMLDocument.I (jquery-2.1.4.min.js:2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just dump the values of your `enum` inside a Javascript variable like this.

You need to convert your `enum` to a comma-separated String then enclose it inside `[]`:

```
var langs = [@Arrays.toString(Languages.values()).replaceAll("^.|.$", "").replaceAll("(?<=[\n, ]?)([^\n, ]+)(?=[\n, ]?)","'$1'")];
```

For your version with `@Prefix`, you just need en enclose your `Scala` variable inside quotes:

```
var prefix = '@Prefix';
```

Comment: The problem is not about how do I split the values in the enum but the problem is the error, why am I not being able to access scala variable in script tag. Check updated question.

Comment: @ParagKadam You can access your variables just fine, you just don't know how to store them in Javascript. Check my code, it'll work. You code is doing `var prefix = en;`, which is not a valid Javascript declaration because the variable `en` is not defined earlier.

Comment: Please check my modified question, it is not even letting me store a String.

Comment: @ParagKadam No problem, you should still edit your question to add your `enum` problem back.